# Triggering a command from a textbox when enter is pressed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox, multibinding

Let me start by saying that I am new to `MVVM`, so please bare with be, if the question is unclear let me know and I will try to clarify.

I have correctly implemented a `button` in `XAML` with `multibinding`, the code is as follows:

```
<Button x:Name="licenceFilterSet" Content="Search License" Command="{Binding licenseSearchCommand}" Click="licenceFilterButtonClick" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="94">
    <Button.Resources>
        <local:SearchFilterConverter x:Key="SearchFilterConverter" />
    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchFilterConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="filterLicenseTextBox" />
            <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="regularExpressionCheckBox" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

(the value of a textbox and a checkbox is sent to be proceed).

Now I would like to add the exact same feature to the textBox, where the user can directly press `ENTER` in the `textBox` and perform the same operation.

I tried the following code, but it seems that each character is now sent to the command, but I only want the command to be sent when the user presses `ENTER`. What should I change?

```
<TextBox Name="filterLicenseTextBox">
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <local:SearchFilterConverter x:Key="SearchFilterConverter" />
        </TextBox.Resources>

        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchFilterConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="filterLicenseTextBox" Mode="OneWay"/>
                <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="regularExpressionCheckBox" Mode="OneWay"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding licenseSearchCommand}">
            </KeyBinding>
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the `MultiBinding` in your `TextBox.Text` is supposed to accomplish... in your `Button`, you had that same code in the `CommandParameter` property instead. Also, please show your `Converter` code.

Comment: just wondering if your question was answers, and if yes, can you accept the answer and close it :)

Answer (score 3):

**The short answer would be:**

use the `IsDefault` on the button:

```
<Button IsDefault="true" 
   Click= "licenceFilterButtonClick"
   Content="Search License" ... />
```

Now the`Enter` key is bound to this button Click, and if you hit `Enter` on any place in the window with the button, it'll work.

**The (bit) long answer would be:**

Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/665886/Button-Tip-IsDefault-IsCancel-and-other-usability), it explains the why (creating a default button), and you can use the cancel as well, once you understand how they work :)